# Change the path where Flutter looks for android emulators

Tags: android, flutter, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Android Studio used to store all the emulators in my SSD. But the SSD just ran out of space, and now the emulators started crashing. So, I figured I need to change their disk location.

To do that, I set an environment variable "ANDROID_SDK_HOME" to somewhere in my HDD. And now when I am creating a new emulator on Android Studio, it is being stored in the new location.

But when I open a flutter project on VS Code, I can not start the emulator using the extension, which used to work fine before changing the location. Now it just won't list the emulator which is stored in a new location, that is why I can't start it from VS Code.

Any help on how to change the path where Flutter extension in VS Code looks for android emulators?